# xsl string separation

Tags: xml, string, xslt, separator

i have an xml on which i apply an xsl and convert to another xml.

The source xml contains a node which gets repeated like this

```
<node>123</node>
<node>456</node>
<node>789</node>
```

I am applying xsl like this

```
<Node><xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='node']/@V"/></Node>
```

the resulting xml is like this

```
<Node>123 456 789</Node>
```

it automatically gets separated by space.

But how can get the values separated by some character like * instead of space.

Comment: Please indicate the target XSLT version and provide a more meaningful sample of your input XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using XSLT 2.0, and the space is appearing because this is the default value of the "separator" attribute. For a different separator such as comma, use

```
<Node><xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='node']/@V" separator=","/></Node>
```

Note that in XSLT 1.0, this instruction would only output the first @V attribute and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop in XSLT to append each string, see:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp

Comment: You could, but there's no reason to make it this complicated.

Answer (score 0):

or `<xsl:apply-templates>` http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_apply_templates.asp